# Explicit closed form of $\mathbb{E}[v_1^iv_2^j]$ from bivariate normal distribution

Tags: distributions, bivariate

Suppose I have a bivariate normal distribution 
$V=\begin{bmatrix}
    v_1 \\
    v_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\mathtt{\sim}\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & a \\
    a & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}\right)$

Define $\theta_s=\sum^s_i\left(\alpha_sv_1^s+\beta_sv_2^s\right)$, where $\alpha_i,\beta_j$ are constants.

Using MGFs, I am able to find a closed form for 
$\mathbb{E}[v_1^i]$:

When $i$ is odd, $\mathbb{E}[v_1^i]=0$.

When $i$ is even, $\mathbb{E}[v_1^i]=\prod_{s=1}^i\left(2s-1\right)$

I am interested in finding a closed form for $\mathbb{E}[v_1^iv_2^j]$ for all $i$'s and $j$'s, which I believe will assist me in finding a closed form for $Var(\theta_s)$ and $Cov(\theta_s,v_1v_2)$.

I have tried writing out specific values for $\mathbb{E}[v_1^iv_2^j]$ but have not arrived at any general form. Even writing them in a recurrence relation is difficult. The only obvious pattern is that $\mathbb{E}[v_1^iv_2^j]=0$ when $i+j$ is odd.

Question 1: Is there a neat way to write the closed form for $\mathbb{E}[v_1^iv_2^j]$ like I have done above for $\mathbb{E}[v_1^i]$?

Question 2: If it is not possible, then what other possible methods are there to obtain a general form for $Var(\theta_s)$ and $Cov(\theta_s,v_1v_2)$.

Merely writing them as the partial derivatives of the MGF is not useful enough as I'm trying to deduce some properties in terms of $a$.

P.S. I obtained the values by defining some functions on Mathematica:

```
Needs["MultivariateStatistics`"]
X = MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1, a}, {a, 1}}]
Theta[s_] := Sum[Subscript[alpha, i] v1^i, {i, 1, s}] + 
 Sum[Subscript[beta, i] v2^i, {i, 1, s}]
Ev1[s_] := Expectation[v1^s, {v1, v2} \[Distributed] X]
Ev2[s_] := Expectation[v2^s, {v1, v2} \[Distributed] X]
Ev1v2[s_, t_] := Expectation[v1^s*v2^t, {v1, v2} \[Distributed] X]
Varv1[s_] := ExpandAll[FullSimplify[Ev1[2 s] - Ev1[s]^2]]
Varv2[s_] := ExpandAll[FullSimplify[Ev2[2 s] - Ev2[s]^2]]
Varv1v2[s_, t_] := ExpandAll[FullSimplify[Ev1v2[s, t] - Ev1[s]*Ev2[t]]]
```

Comment: Did you perhaps omit some powers of $v_1$ and $v_2$ in your definition of $\theta_s$?

Comment: Yes I did. Edited.

Comment: I believe you meant to use powers (and indexes) of $i$ rather than $s$.

Comment: Since$$V_2|V_1=v_1\sim \mathcal{N}\left(\alpha v_1,\ (1-\alpha^2)\right)$$ one can use a decomposition of $\mathbb{E}[V_1^a V_2^b]$ as $\mathbb{E}[V_1^a \mathbb{E}[V_2^b|V_1]]$

Comment: Could you elaborate please?